# Does a random effects meta analysis produce the mean of population effect sizes?

Tags: meta-analysis

In a random effects meta analysis of correlation coefficients, is the outcome the mean of a distribution of population correlation coefficients? If so, is this denoted rho symbol (p) with a hat on? I have seen studies refer to it as just an "estimate of the population correlation coefficient," so does this assume the reader will know it refers to an estimate of **an average** and not a single population effect size? Given the random effects model assumes there is not just one population effect size to find but many different ones?

Comment: population "correlation coefficient," can be  either an estimate or an observed directly computed quantity. For an estimation, several independent samples may be  used. Alternanatively,  repeat sampling from a specified population may  be conducted.

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, a random-effects model fitted to a bunch of observed correlation coefficients provides an estimate of the *average* of the true correlation coefficients in a population of studies from which the studies included in our meta-analysis have come.

So, to be precise, let $r_1, r_2, \ldots, r_k$ denote the observed correlation coefficients for the $k$ studies included in our meta-analysis. In each of these studies, there is an underlying true correlation which we can denote with $\rho_1, \rho_2, \ldots, \rho_k$. Imagine we would conduct each study with a very very large sample size; then the observed correlations would be in essence these underlying true correlations.

These $k$ true correlations are assumed to have come from a population of true correlations. One way to imagine this is to think of a population of studies, consisting of studies that were actually conducted, but also containing studies that could have been conducted hypothetically (yes, this part gets a bit abstract).

We typically assume that the true correlations in this population are normally distributed (or at least, approximately so) and hence we write $\rho_i \sim N(\mu_\rho, \tau_\rho^2)$. The random-effects model provides us an estimate of $\mu_\rho$ and $\tau_\rho^2$, which we can denote $\hat{\mu}_\rho$ and $\hat{\tau}_\rho^2$.

Some may use other notation for $\hat{\mu}_\rho$, such as $\hat{\bar{\rho}}$ (so a hat for denoting that this is an estimate and the bar on top of $\rho$ to denote that this is an average). I do not like this notation, because it does not draw a clear distinction between the average in the population of studies (i.e., $\mu_\rho$) and the average of the true correlations of the $k$ studies included in the meta-analysis (i.e., the average of $\rho_1, \rho_2, \ldots, \rho_k$). The random-effects model does not estimate the latter; it estimates the average in the population of studies.

Even worse would be just writing $\hat{\rho}$ for $\hat{\mu}_\rho$. That would be outright incorrect notation as far as I am concerned, because it gives the impression that we are estimating one correlation coefficient.